# Updating state when some prop changes without useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I've come across React's recommendation to [avoid using useEffect for internal React updates](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#adjusting-some-state-when-a-prop-changes). While the suggested solutions in the link work, they might be challenging to manage and extend.

Currently, I'm using below hook, and it seems to be working well. However, I'm unsure if there are any performance advantages to using useEffect or if there are better solutions available. Could someone provide insights or recommendations, please?

```js
const shouldUpdate = (dependencies = [], prevDependencies = []) => {
  if (!prevDependencies) return true;
  if (!dependencies.length) return false;

  for (const index in dependencies) {
    if (!Object.is(dependencies[index], prevDependencies[index])) return true;
  }

  return false;
};

export function useDerivedState(callBack, dependencies = [], shouldRunFirstTime = true) {
  const [prevDependencies, setPrevDependencies] = useState(() =>
    shouldRunFirstTime ? null : dependencies
  );

  if (shouldUpdate(dependencies, prevDependencies)) {
    callBack();
    setPrevDependencies([...dependencies]);
  }
}
```

**Use case:**

```js
const Component = ({ triggerX, ...otherProps }) => {
  const [list, setList] = useState(() => getList(otherProps))
  const [otherState, setOtherState] = useState(someInitialValue)
    // other states and refs

  useDerivedState(() => {
    // getNewValue or do some other React operations
    setList(getTriggerXList(list))
  }, [triggerX]);

    // other triggers and handlers

  return // render or hook args
};
```

Comment: you are calling `callBack` during render phase this way. So it can't contain side effects.

Comment: Yep, It's normally used for updating state: `setSomething(otherThing)`

Comment: I see what you are trying to achieve now, well I think you chose bad naming, call it `useDerivedState` or something...

Comment: Thanks! `useDerivedState` sounds more appropriate. I started using it instead of useEffect and named it `useMyEffect` but it's purpose is to be used when changes are not outside React.

Comment: it looks like you just rewrote useMemo, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: It's more about encapsulating the logic mentioned [here](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#adjusting-some-state-when-a-prop-changes). Specially, when there are multiple dependencies.